# Send Broadcast from service to update the list fragment for every 1 minute

Tags: android, android-service

I have a service which runs on 24 hours daily.This service is started by an Activity and it runs indefinably. Inside the service, a separate thread runs and fetch data from server for every 1 minute. So whenever updated I used `sendBroadcast` to update the List Fragment and receive message from service and restart the Loader to update the List Fragment.

1. Is this method is correct or not?
2. If the listfragement(has broadcast receiver) destroyed the `sendBroadcast` produce any problem?

Comment: is the ListFragment only associated with the activity or it is displayed in homescreen widget or notifications ?

Comment: It is associated with an Activity.

Comment: In that case why do you want the service to be running the whole time requesting the server? You can just request when the activity is in view (startService in onResume/oncreate and stop in onPause).

Comment: Because I want to store the data in local sqlite database table to provide last updated data,even network not available.

Comment: Also the background service generates notification whenever certain conditions meet.

Comment: consider the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrap the whole thing and start from scratch :) Running '24 hours daily' is mostly impossible on Android, because it will go to sleep once the screen turns off. If you force it to stay on you will eat the battery in no time at all. So scrap that part. Updating data from server every minute is a bad idea too: too many network calls will the battery, and may take a long time on a 3G network. Additionally, the user probably doesn't care about those updates when they are in another app, so you will be wasting resources fetching things no one will ever see.

Use AralamManager to schedule periodic updates for your service if you have to. Re-consider the 'each minute' part. Have the activity register itself for updates `onStart()` and unregister `onStop()`.

Comment: I need to run the service for whole day.Because it will generate notifications whenever certain conditions meet.Also i need to display a home screen widget based on this background service.Is it any other way?

Comment: If you need to notify when server state changes consider using GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) for push notifications. Otherwise schedule your service to run once each hour/15 mins, etc. Always-on is not an option.

Comment: So I will add an option in settings with Interval-1 min,5 min,10 min,60 min to the user. He/She can choose the option based on the their need.

Comment: You can do that. 1 and 5 mins are a bad idea though, except for testing.

Comment: Thank you.Also I try to schedule the service based on the user needs.

Comment: Forgot about question Main part.Using sendBroadcast from service and receive in Listfragment and update loader is correct way?

Comment: It depends. Does it work? Not sure where the loader comes in?

Comment: The Loader Manager is used to query data from SQLite and update list fragment.This loader should restart to update the list fragment whenever data updated by service

Comment: Makes sense. The only tricky bit is that you should register/unregister the receiver in order not to get broadcasts you cannot process when in background.

Comment: I registered and unregistered broadcast receivers in Activity's OnStart and onStop callbacks. So whenever activity starts it receiving broadcast and update list fragment.If Activity stopped,the broadcast receiver unregisters. But the service still runs and sendBroadcast.

Comment: Re: the receiver: sounds good. If don't stop the service it will continue running. Consider using an `IntentService` started via `AlaramManager`. It will automatically create a worker thread and shut itself down when done.

Comment: Yes I will use Intent Service using Alarm Manager.Thank your quick responses